git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git
I'm trying to clone the git repot at https://github.com/kortina/dotfiles
I have done this many times, and I'm sure I'm doing something silly.
First, I tried using the old ~/.ssh/known_hosts file on my computer:
> grep github.com known_hosts
github.com,192.30.255.112 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
gist.github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==


git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git
Cloning into 'dotfiles'...
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/kortina/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/kortina/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


Yikes, repo is way out of date!
Next, I tried following this Why are connections to GitHub over SSH throwing an error "Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed"?
I set my ~/.ssh/known_hosts to:
> cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
github.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl
github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=
github.com ssh-rsa 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

> git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git
Cloning into 'dotfiles'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

But the repository is public, and I got the above error.
Next, I tried just blowing away my known_hosts and got the following error:
git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git
Cloning into 'dotfiles'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

Q1: why does it say "(yes/no/[fingerprint])" in this output file?
I put yes and got the error:
Cloning into 'dotfiles'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Finally, I tried switching from
git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git

to
git clone https://github.com/kortina/dotfiles/
git add .
git commit -m "tweaks"
git push origin master
[master 67e8367] tweaks
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Username for 'https://github.com': kortina
Password for 'https://kortina@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/kortina/dotfiles/'

Q2: Why is this failing?
Ultimately, I'd love to get this back to the point where I had everything working with the original git command but I just cannot seem to figure this out...

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

You need generate .ssh key and upload public key in you github account.
example you problem:
in my user has not keys in .ssh
root@surgai:~# ls -lah .ssh/
drwx------ 2 root root 4,0K ноя 13 09:24 .
drwx------ 8 root root 4,0K ноя 13 09:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142 ноя 13 09:24 known_hosts
Check login:
root@surgai:~# ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
Check clone:
root@surgai:~# git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git
Cloning into  «dotfiles»...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Fix:
make key:
root@surgai:~# ssh-keygen -t ed25519
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_ed25519):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
Now upload /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub in you githib account - https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
And check:
root@surgai:~# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi surgai! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Clonning now success:
root@surgai:~# git clone git@github.com:kortina/dotfiles.git
Cloning into «dotfiles»...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5072, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1761/1761), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (577/577), done.
remote: Total 5072 (delta 1133), reused 1687 (delta 1078), pack-reused 3311 (from 1)

Try not using SSH. You can try your password or a personal access key. Follow these step(s):

Run git clone https://github.com/kortina/dotfiles/.

Make a classic personal access token, or a fine grained personal access token.

Follow these steps to use it on the command line.




But the repository is public, and I got the above error.

The error message is not about access to the repository – it is about access to GitHub's SSH server as a whole; the repository comes after you've connected to the server in general.
GitHub's SSH service does not support anonymous access – specifically because the repository is only named after you've connected, so during connection it doesn't yet know whether you're about to clone a public repo or not (and therefore doesn't know whether it should ask for a key or not).
Follow GitHub's instructions for setting up a personal SSH key (with ssh-keygen if needed) and uploading it to your GitHub account.

Next, I tried just blowing away my known_hosts and

That wasn't necessary, as the previous error ("Permission denied (publickey)") was not related to known_hosts in any way – the known_hosts error had already been fixed by updating the entries. The "Permission denied" error was about your personal key not being recognized by GitHub, i.e. in the opposite direction than known_hosts.

Q1: why does it say "(yes/no/[fingerprint])" in this output file?

You don't have any known_hosts entry for the server anymore (as you just removed it), and SSH doesn't have any automatic way to verify that the server's key it's seeing is indeed the correct key for "github.com". (Unlike HTTPS where Certificate Authorities automate this, the server keys in SSH are not 'certified' by anyone external.)
So it's expecting you to manually check the fingerprint (e.g. against the one listed in GitHub's help pages) – or to paste a known-valid fingerprint from GitHub's help site and have SSH compare them.
Accept the fingerprint (it seems to be correct), then run the command again. If it doesn't work, try again bypassing Git – i.e. run ssh git@github.com and see if it connects at all.

Q2: Why is this failing?

The message already explains why. The clone command did not fail (it seems to have successfully cloned the public repository), but the push command did, because GitHub has decided to no longer accept passwords via git clone – they now require randomly-generated "access tokens".
(Primarily that's because various 2FA technologies like FIDO passkeys don't translate well to command-line tools, at least not without adding provider-specific knowledge to the general Git software.)
